# Excel VBA, update specific sheets not just the active sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I created a script that hides rows in my active sheet if the row has a "-".  I would like to apply this to other sheets (i.e.  Sheet-ABC, Sheet-DEF) as well. I tried using an array, but was unsuccessful.

Any help is appreciated.

```
Sub hideRows()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.DisplayAlerts = False


Dim cell, cell2 As Range, hRws As Range
Set Rng = Sheet15.Range("A52:L359")

Rng.EntireRow.Hidden = False

For Each cell In Range("A52:L359").SpecialCells(xlBlanks)
If cell = "-" And cell.Offset(-1, 0) = "-" Then
If hRws Is Nothing Then
Set hRws = Range(cell, cell.Offset(1, 0))

Else
Set hRws = Union(hRws, Range(cell, cell.Offset(1, 0)))
End If
End If
Next

If Not hRws Is Nothing Then hRws.EntireRow.Hidden = True

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Ummm - if you are looping through blank cells, how many will have a value of `"-"`?

Answer (score 0):

You can call your hideRows() method inside a for-loop. Something like this:

`Dim ws As Worksheet
 For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
     hideRows()
 Next`

Comment: That won't work (a) until the problems in `hideRows` are fixed (e.g. it's hiding rows on one worksheet and unhiding them on a potentially different one, it's looping through blank cells looking for a "-", etc) (b) because you aren't letting `hideRows` know what worksheet to process (c) the OP only wants to process certain worksheets rather than all worksheets (i.e. it would probably need to be `For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(Array("Sheet-ABC", "Sheet-DEF"))`).

Comment: I tried YowE3K's suggestion with no success.  The active worksheet is the only one that is affected.

Comment: I think my code is dying on this reference when I use the For Each loop:

`Set Rng = **ws**.Range("A52:L359")`

So through each iteration of the loop, how do I update the Rng variable with the new sheet name?  The above code doesn't work.

Comment: I got the For Each loop to loop through each sheet. But it dies on this part of the code

`Set hRws = Union(hRws, Range(cell, cell.Offset(1, 0))) `

Says Global "union" failed etc...